# Light Table IDE does not show Code Assist

Tags: lighttable

In Light Table IDE, how can I see "Code Assist" or "Code Help", like in the photo (the photo is from their official website) Please help...[code assist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/429OW.png)
I would like to see a code description or parameters of a function. Thanks

I highlighted a HTML tag but it does not show it.